# Alphabetic gesture recognition in iOS

Tags: ios

I am working on detecting alphabetic gestures in my app. So when the user draws a C in the screen C should be displayed on a label and so on.  How to detect which alphabet is drawn by user ?

Comment: This may be help you. It have numerical. https://github.com/bengotow/BGNumericalGlyphRecognizer

Comment: I have used this but this is not recognising the characters correctly. Can recognise the characters drawn on the screen using tesseract which is used for image recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this. This site have unistroke recognizer http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/